# Flutter calling api with token in bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am following bloc tutorial and trying to make a app with login and then call apis with token getting from login api.

After reading the bloc tutorial, I am thinking that after login process, the token may be stored inside a something like authentication repository.

But for the rest of apis call which need the token got from login, how do the api clients get the token?

I am wondering if I inject the authentication repository to all api clients, it would be quite messy.

So is there any clean way to do this in bloc pattern?

Thanks

my structure

```
├── android
├── ios
├── lib
├── packages
│   ├── authentication_repository
│   └── login_api
│   └── other_apis
│   └── ...
└── test
```

Comment: If you use a library like dio (https://pub.dev/packages/dio), you could easily pass the token through the "interceptors".

Answer (score 1):

I also used **BLOC** pattern in my project. As my option, you can build **base  network class** and you can inject auth token for other rest of the API. I will show my code example.

This is header method work for getting token.

```
class BaseNetwork {
  final Client _client = Client();

  Future<Map<String, String>> getHeader({required String url}) async {
    String? token =
        await SharedPref.retrieveData(key: SharedPref.loginAuthToken);
    switch (url) {
      case END_POINT_SEND_DEVICE_INFO:
      case END_POINT_ID_LOGIN:
        return {'Authorization': StaticConstant.basicToken};
      default:
        return {'Authorization': '${StaticConstant.token} ${token!}'};
    }
  }
```

Here is the **API fetching method** calling method that called `getHeader()` method.

```
  Future<ResponseObject> postRequest(
      {String baseURL = BASE_URL,
      required String endURL,
      required Map<String, dynamic> requestBody}) async {
    ResponseObject responseOb =
        ResponseObject(messageState: MessageState.loading);
    return await getHeader(url: endURL).then((headerValue) async {
      return await _client
          .post(Uri.parse(baseURL + endURL),
              body: requestBody, headers: headerValue)
          .then((res) {
       debugPrint('request body ---- $requestBody');
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          responseOb.data = res.body;
          responseOb.messageState = MessageState.data;
         debugPrint('successResponse ---- ${responseOb.data}');
          return responseOb;
        } else {
          responseOb.data = res.body;
          responseOb.messageState = MessageState.serverError;
         debugPrint('errorResponse ---- ${responseOb.data}');
          return responseOb;
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit:** By extending base class from respective api repo. You can call clearly.

```
class LoginDataSource extends BaseNetwork {
  
  @override
  Future<ResponseObject> login(
      {required String loginEndPoint,
      required Map<String, dynamic> loginRequestBody}) async {
    ResponseObject responseObject =
        ResponseObject(messageState: MessageState.loading);
    return await postRequest(
            endURL: loginEndPoint, requestBody: loginRequestBody)
        .then(
      (ResponseObject value) {
        print("LoginValue === ${value.data}");
        if (value.messageState == MessageState.data) {
          Map<String, dynamic> loginRawData = json.decode(value.data!);
          if (filterVO.responseCode == 200) {
            responseObject.data = loginRawData;
            responseObject.messageState = MessageState.data;

/// Here you can save token that get from login api

            return responseObject;
          } else {
            responseObject.messageState = MessageState.requestError;
            responseObject.data = ErrorHandlingModel.fromJson(loginRawData);
            return responseObject;
          }
        } else {
          responseObject.messageState == MessageState.serverError;
          responseObject.data = value.data;
          return responseObject;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Do you mean like that? If not, don't mind. I show as much as I can.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I see you have a base network client, which will retrieve token from local storage (SharedPref). So I think it is a method. But what I am looking for is, I have a authentication repository, which have cached the token and stored inside the repository, and I want to usse the cached token instead of every time I get token from local storage. But thanks for your answer. If I cant find other way, may try this getting from local storage way.

Comment: I think, you can check condition in as me with ```Switch``` case inside of authentication repo. Check the present or absent of**cached token**. Do you asked like that?

Comment: no. I am asking, how to get the cached token, which stored in a authentication repo, in your base network class. Do I need to inject the repo to the base network? If so, then for all api client which using the base network class also need to be injected with the repo.